# Ternary operator without second operand

Tags: c++, c, gcc, operators, conditional-operator

This is a two legged question: one for C and one for C++.

What the C and C++ standards have to say about the following use of the ternary (`?:`) operator:

```
const char* opt = /* possible NULL pointer */;
const char* str = opt ?: "";
```

When did it became legal? Is it a compiler extension? What are the requirements on the first operand (implicitly convertible to `bool`/`int`)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GCC provides this as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html). This is not in the C++ standard.

The semantics are that if the condition is nonzero, the value of the expression is that of the condition.

The implicit requirement is that the condition must be type-compatible with the third operand, i.e. one can be converted to the other following the usual conditional operator rules.

It's important to note that if the condition is computed from a function with side effects, the value will *not* be recomputed with this extension:

```
opt() ?: ""; //opt called once
opt() ? opt() : ""; //opt called twice
```

Answer (score 12):

The ternary operator with omitted middle operand:

```
const char* str = opt ?: "";
```

is a GNU extension it's not standard C++.

Comment: Thank you. And what is the requirement on it's first operand?

Comment: @YSC: The condition and truth values are coalesced: `opt ?: ""` is equivalent to `opt ? opt : ""` .

Comment: TartanLlama already gave that answer.

Comment: @101010 Actually, this answer is provided before Tartan's.